# Android canvas.drawPoint ignores Paint.Cap round

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I've been working on this for a while. This code:

```
Log.i(TAG, "stroke style: " + paint.getStyle());
Log.i(TAG, "stroke cap: " + paint.getStrokeCap());
canvas.drawPoint(p.x, p.y, paint);
```

prints 'STROKE' and 'ROUND' to the logs, but draws a black SQUARE to the map! Anyone know what I need to be doing differently to produce a dot instead of a square!?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I'm going to give the below suggestion(s) of using drawCircle a shot, but I was just confused I guess because everything I've read indicates you should be able to indicate you want a circle that way. One example being [this google book entry](http://books.google.com/books?id=TwV45aVC14IC&pg=PT432&dq=android%20setstrokecap%20does%20nothing%20point&hl=en&sa=X&ei=z7IrUYmeK4XWygHT1IEw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA)

Comment: I think cap options are for `Path`s and not for `Shapes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [drawCircle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle%28float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) with `p.x` and `p.y` as center (first and second argument) and use `1 or 2` as radius depend on how big you want the dot to be and use the `paint` with stroke style `FILL`..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `drawCircle` instead

```
circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
circlePaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000); //opaque red
float radius = 10f; //10 pixels

canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p,y, radius, circlePaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

It draws correctly if you draw to a canvas backed by a bitmap. It doesn't seem to draw correctly if you draw directly to the screen (i.e. a canvas passed to a View's onDraw() method). Another way of getting around the problem is, therefore, to first render to a bitmap and then draw that to the screen.